# selecting from dropdown list does not populate a second dependent drop list because of browser warning

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

This is my first post on stack overflow, but as a novice I visit it often for answers but on this question I can't find an existing answer that helps me - because of my limited knowledge.

My website uses a prebuilt shop application - for which support is no longer available - which I have modified extensively over a number of years. There are checkout pages which feature a dropdown for Country and a second dependent dropdown for State.

I removed the dropdowns entirely a long time ago because of a problem behaviour which I couldn't fix but now I have to reinstate the dropdowns (and their problem code) because my payment gateway is changing to a standardised country code and state code requirement.

What happens is that when a selection is made from the Country dropdown, the code submits the form before a selection can be made from the States dropdown; at this point the browser puts up an alert asking for confirmation that you want to leave the page you are on.

If you answer 'No' then you are stuck because the States dropdown remains empty and in any case the form's buttons (next, back, cancelled) now do nothing. On the other hand if you answer 'Yes' then the next checkout form is loaded in the browser and in that form you have to use the Back button to go back to the first form where the States dropdown is now populated and you can now make a selection, then use the 'next' button etc. Clearly not a viable process for a user because most will answer 'no' and simply get stuck.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="KT_th"><label for="country_ord">Country:</label></td>
    <td>
        <select name="country_ord" id="country_ord" onChange="submitMe(this)">
            <option value="" >Choose one...</option>
                <?php 
                    do {  
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_rsCountry['iso2_cnt']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_rsCountry['iso2_cnt'], $row_rsorder_ord['country_ord']))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>
                <?php echo $row_rsCountry['name_cnt']?></option>
                <?php
                    } while ($row_rsCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCountry));
                    $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCountry);
                    if($rows > 0) {
                        mysql_data_seek($rsCountry, 0);
                        $row_rsCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCountry);
                    }
                ?>
        </select>
          <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("order_ord", "country_ord"); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="KT_th"><label for="state_ord">State (REQUIRED for USA only):</label (optional)></td>
    <td>
        <select name="state_ord" id="state_ord">
            <option value="">Choose one ...</option>
<?php 
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_rsStates['code_sta']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_rsStates['code_sta'], $row_rsorder_ord['state_ord']))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_rsStates['name_sta']?></option>
          <?php
} while ($row_rsStates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStates));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsStates);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsStates, 0);
  $row_rsStates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStates);
  }
?>
        </select>
          <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("order_ord", "state_ord"); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="KT_buttons">
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="button" onClick="MM_goToURL('parent','index.php?mod=cartview');return document.MM_returnValue" value="&lt; Previous">
        <input type="submit" name="KT_Update1" id="KT_Update1" value="Next &gt;">
        <input name="button_cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="document.location = 'index.php?mod=cartview'">
        <input type="hidden" name="validate_form" value="1">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>
function submitMe(el) 
{
var frm = el.form;
frm.action = window.location.href;
frm.elements.state_ord.selectedIndex = 0;
frm.elements.validate_form.value = 0;
KT_FVO = {};
frm.elements.KT_Update1.click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Being a novice doesn't matter. The best you can do is to convey something crisp and share only the relevant code, indented well for better readability, and both are lacking in your post!

Comment: Sorry, I know that I have a lot to learn. If I have posted rather too much it is because I tried to give enough information to help someone who might have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent submitting when the value of the pull-down is selected remove this:

```
 onChange="submitMe(this)"

from this:
<select name="country_ord" id="country_ord" onChange="submitMe(this)">

to this:
<select name="country_ord" id="country_ord">
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers so far - what a fantatic quick response!. I am unable to test further for the rest of this afternoon (other duties) but I will respond later today with the results.

Comment: I guess you meant to put it here:

Comment: Oops, I pressed return and posted before ready. I guess you meant put it here:         <select name="state_ord" id="state_ord"> . But that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

On country selection, Don't submit the form. Simply place an Ajax call that will fill your states box. On selection of all the required params in the form, submit the form.
Even if you still want to go for form submission on country selection, on submission check if all data you need like states is filled or not. if not, load the same page with states data for selected country. next time user will select states and submit, than check all required data like states is present, load the function or page where your other stuff with data is to be done.

Comment: I don't want the form to be submitted automatically at all. I want the same page to stay put until the user explicitly clicks the 'Next' button which is on the form. So what I really need is the the action for elect in the countries dropdown populates the States dropdown and - and perhaps it then needs to refresh the same page but not move on to the next page?

Comment: thats what i said. make an ajax call. in jquery - $('#country').change(funciton(){.... // make ajax call to states list url, echo states  and on success, replace states dropdown with ajax data- }).

Comment: Thanks but its over my head, I struggle with php never mind getting into javascript as well. If you could expand your code example it would be a great help, if that's not asking too much of your time.

Comment: $('#country').change(funciton(){ var country_id=$('#country').val(); $.ajax({
                                            type: "GET",
                                            url: "/states/"+country_id, success: function (a) { $('#states').html(a) });  // a will be the html output from ///states/country_id page
                                        });

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to expand that code. For the moment I have adopted a workaround but when I have time I will see if I can implement your solution. Workaround is forget the dependent dropdown and instead display the Country and States as two independent dropdowns. The Country is required field but the States is not; States filled only with US states, labelling indicates that a State choice is only required for the USA (which is all that my gateway, SagePay, requires). A kludge but OK for now, July 31st deadline looms SagePay stops processing payments with existing integration.